# Limiting the size of spans inside a button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button which consists of one Icon on the left side of it, one span in the middle which contains a name of product ( the name can be really large) and another span on the right side, which shows a number of message notifications. I could  limit the size of the text with this CSS
Edit: if i set the text-overflow to the span inside the button, it wont work at all.

```
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

the problem is this also makes the message notification span on the right, to display "..." i need the span on the middle to be limited but also to see the text on the right span. Any ideas? this is the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" style="
    display: inline-block;>
                            <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>                               
                            <span>JULIERME ALFREDO MADKE</span>                               

                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        </button>
```

Comment: Dont use the css on the right side span.

Comment: Forgot to mention i also tried that, the css doesnt work on the span, only on the button

Comment: I would suggest, moving your spans outside of the button, and wrapping everything in a div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create  code pen for you, see if this the on you're looking for : [code pen example](https://codepen.io/bhimbim/pen/xpNQLj?editors=1100). Please ask if you need more explanation, thank you.

HTML

```
<!-- Question Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428590/limiting-the-size-of-spans-inside-a-button#48428590 -->

<button type="button">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-group-512.png"/>
  <span class="Name">Ibrahim Aziz asd asd asd asd asd asd</span>
  <span class="Notification">14</span>
</button>
```

CSS

```
button
{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

button img
{
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  align-self: center;
}

button span.Name
{
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

button span.Notification
{
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dedede;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: i ended up using position absolute on the notification span, thanks for the awnser tho, your solution looks more elegant than mine, ill study the display flex later when i have the time! have a nice day.

Comment: you're welcome, let me know if you have more question.